# send the custom message to triggered send Marketing cloud via Rest or SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have setup the **Triggered Send MC** - API Integration & it is working absolutely fine.
I now want to send the *custom message* to Triggered Send to set the custom Email Content, via JSON response.
How can I accomplish this task?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have a placeholder in the email for your custom message? Basically what you need to do is add something like `%%=v(AttributeValue("custom_message"))=%%` to the triggered send email, and then pass that `custom_message` via JSON. Take a look here for Triggered Sends 101: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/25/introduction-to-triggered-sends/

Comment: @zuzannamj you meant that I need to use the AMPscript to pass the custom message?

Comment: You need to use an AMPscript placeholder inside the email and pass the message thought API if you want it to be displayed inside the email

Comment: Yeah I did understand. Actually, I wanted it to work without using AMPscript but after reading the articles I also came to know that I need to use ampscript.
Thank you @zuzannamj